# js iframe close button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I Have the following which opens an iframe with html page loaded, works great, but how to add a close button to the page/iframe so it simply closes the iframe/page and does not affect the page its opened over:

```
(function (d) {
var modal = document.createElement('iframe');
modal.setAttribute('src', 'mypage.html'));
modal.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
modal.className = 'modal';document.body.appendChild(modal);
var c = document.createElement('link');
c.type = 'text/css';
c.rel = 'stylesheet';
c.href = '//myurl.com/testes.css';
document.body.appendChild(c);
}(document));
```

I tried the following which tried to close it, but, then gives a 404 message inside the iframe:

```
<a href="window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe').parentNode.removeChild(window.parent.document.getElementById('iframe'))">Close</a>
```

I am loading jquery on the page if that helps at all, meaning, if there is a jquery solution.

Answer (score 2):

Links are supposed to link somewhere and the `href` attribute takes a URI.

Use a `<button type="button">` and bind a click handler to it. (You could use an `onclick` attribute, but that wouldn't be [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript))

The unobtrusive approach would be:

```
<a href="someUriWithoutAnIframe" target="_parent">foo</a>
```

And then bind an event handler along the lines of

```
myLink.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var d = window.parent.document;
    var frame = d.getElementById('myFrame');
    frame.parentNode.removeChild(frame);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: One can also use the 'javascript:' prefix in the `href`: `<a href="javascript:alert('Hello, world!');">Click me</a>`

Comment: There are lots of things that can be done, but fewer that should be done, and that is one of them.

Comment: I was just adding to the options :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could put the link into some kind of container div for your iframe, creating the latter with this structure:

```
<div id="iframe-container">
  <a href='#' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode)'>Close</a>
  <iframe src="http://some.web/page.html" />
</div>
```

Works without any framework.